# Does Hydrogen Gas need to be bubbled in during Reduction of the electrode?

Tags: electrochemistry, hydrogen

I have read in textbooks and websites that hydrogen gas needs to be bubbled into the SHE (Standard Hydrogen Electrode). I understand why for oxidation of the half cell - the gas is oxidised into H+ (aq) and the electrons move into the other half cell. Anions from the salt bridge then move to maintain cell neutrality.

However, I fail to understand why hydrogen gas needs to be bubbled into the cell during reduction, as hydrogen intake is not needed. As H+ (aq) gets reduced into gas, it will just bubble out whereever it is formed, not necessarily through the tube. Cations from the salt bridge move to maintain neutrality.

I suspect that it is something to do to maintain stability/neutrality. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What potential would SHE have if you did not bubble H2 through it?

Comment: You use a salt bridge only to close the electric circuit (i.e., charge transport).  It is filled e.g. with diluted aq. $\ce{KCl}$,* and plugged by diaphragms to hinder the travel of $\ce{K+}$ / $\ce{Cl-}$ into either one half cell across this boundary.  You *do not* want a travel of matter (e.g., $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$) across this connection into the other half-cell.
<br/>
\* An example of a strong electrolyte (i.e., complete dissociation) of ions with similar mobility which are not subject to electrochemical reaction in the difference of electrode potentials of your intended half-cell reaction(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_hydrogen_electrode) is not used as a working electrode with passing current, it would affect its potential.

It is used as the third, reference electrode with negligible current. The potentials of the working anode and/or cathode with eventually passing significant current are then measured against SHE.

Similarly are used other, more practical [calomel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_calomel_electrode) or [argentchloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_chloride_electrode) reference electrodes $\ce{Hg|Hg2Cl2|KCl}$ or $\ce{Ag|AgCl|KCl}$. The latter is often integrated with pH glass electrode, forming the compact 2-electrode pH sensor.

Note that the real potential of SHE with deviations of $a_{\ce{H+}}$  or $p_{\ce{H2}}$ is:

$$E_\mathrm{SHE} = E^{\circ}_\mathrm{SHE} + \frac{RT}{2F} \ln{\left(\frac{a_{\ce{H+}}^2}{p_{\ce{H2}}}\right)}$$

The SHE requires $a_{\ce{H+}}=1$ and $p_{\ce{H2}}=\pu{1 atm}$, with the solution saturated by hydrogen. This can be hardly done other way than by bubbling hydrogen through the solution, what is BTW the part of SHE definition.